# Website Migration - Large SQL file and Public_html

Tags: mysql, import

We're importing a large number of databases/migrating for a client of mine.

The issue we're having is that due to their current host, who they are leaving for myself, is that we only have user access to their Cpanel account via SSH.

Particular sites, that have large(5GB+) site files are becoming a problem for us, we cannot .zip them due to the fact that their current host will not provide a larger quota for the migration. However as far as I'm aware it is not possible to SCP or rsync a directory is it? Any thoughts on this?

Also the SQL databases are quite large and I'm having issues importing them via the terminal. Is there a way to import large SQL files without any problems occurring?(Phpmyadmin is not an option)

Hope someone can help!!

Comment: what is `quota`? disk space? bandwidth?

Comment: I am unsure of the quota of their old host. Anything over 1.5GB comes back with a quota error when zipping the files. My VPS/Dedi has unlimited quota. 

Bandwidth isn't great. However I am at the point now where it just needs to get done.